# How to use Pandas dataframe transform 2D dataset into 3D?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index, 2d-3d-conversion

I have a tropical cyclone dataset like this:
[TC dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AAbpn.png)

I want to group the dataset according to the column 'TC_name', i.e. one TC one group, but 'TC_name' may be identical for different years and the same TC may travel interannually, so `groupby()` maybe doesn't work.

I also tried to loop line by line and find where the 'TC_name' changes, cut the dataset there to get a dataframe for each TC. However, this gives me over 1000 dataframes and I don't know how to represent this 2D information in a 3D formation.

I guess `multi index` might work through assigning a high level `index` to each TC, but I cannot reach it after trying many times.

An example is provided below for clarification: (I need seperate 3 tropical cyclones)

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'TC_name':['RITA','RITA','IDA','IDA','IDA','IDA','RITA','RITA','RITA'],
        'Year':[2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2021,2021,2021,2021]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df
```

```
    TC_name Year
0   RITA    2020
1   RITA    2020
2   IDA     2020
3   IDA     2020
4   IDA     2020
5   IDA     2021
6   RITA    2021
7   RITA    2021
8   RITA    2021
```

And it would be better to get this format, or any other efficient 3D data structure representation.

```
         TC_name    Year
   1   1    RITA    2020
       2    RITA    2020
   2   1    IDA     2020
       2    IDA     2020
       3    IDA     2020
       4    IDA     2021
   3   1    RITA    2021
       2    RITA    2021
       3    RITA    2021
```

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Why does `RITA (2020)` get number 1 assigned and `IDA (2020)` number 2 and not vice-versa? Is there some kind of implied order in the dataset?

Comment: The data is initially sorted by the time of occurrence. Actually, the order is not important. I just give a possible output by which I can access one TC track quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Edit

Here another possibility. We reset the index to keep the original sorting:

```
df = df.reset_index()
```

Then we assign a new id **within** each `TC_name` group:

```
df['id2'] = df.groupby('TC_name')['index'].transform(lambda x: pd.factorize(x)[0] + 1)
```

Here the intermediate output:

|  | index | TC_name | Year | id2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | RITA | 2020 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | RITA | 2020 | 2 |
| 2 | 2 | IDA | 2020 | 1 |
| 3 | 3 | IDA | 2020 | 2 |
| 4 | 4 | IDA | 2020 | 3 |
| 5 | 5 | IDA | 2021 | 4 |

Then we assign a new id every time the TC_name changes:

```
df['id'] = (df["TC_name"] != df["TC_name"].shift(1)).cumsum()
```

And finally we drop the `index` and set the multiindex:

```
df = df.drop('index', axis=1).set_index(['id', 'id2'])
```

Here the final output, which looks like yours:

|  |  | TC_name | Year |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | RITA | 2020 |
|  | 2 | RITA | 2020 |
| 2 | 1 | IDA | 2020 |
|  | 2 | IDA | 2020 |
|  | 3 | IDA | 2020 |
|  | 4 | IDA | 2021 |
| 3 | 3 | RITA | 2021 |
|  | 4 | RITA | 2021 |
|  | 5 | RITA | 2021 |

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. However, please also note that there are `IDA(2020)` and `IDA(2021)`, so `groupby` is not applicable for this issue. Any other insights on how to split this dataset are also appreciated.

Comment: In fact, I tried `groupby()` before asking. Adding `sort = False` in `groupby` will give the output in the original sort, which is almost there.

Comment: I edited the answer to provide another way. Do you need a separate sorting for the second level of the index (reset the "counter")?

Comment: Thanks, but there are actually only 3 groups. Although `IDA` begins in 2020 and ends in 2021, it is still 'one' cyclone.

Comment: I think I have it (finally) :)

Comment: This is the first time I use Stackoverflow and I am just a beginner in python programming. Really cannot believe I find a fantastic platform to support my programming study. Thanks again. Have a nice day! :)